# How to test against text or math mode in ConTeXt?

Tags: math-mode, conditionals, context, text-mode

I want a `\doifmode` for text mode or a `\doifnotmode` for math mode but math and text are not defined as [system modes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes#System_modes) by ConTeXt.

Hungarian typography requires small space before certain characters, including colons. I want to adapt that. However I want to avoid that for non-text modes.

Unfortunately I can not write a conditional code based on text/math mode which is rather frustrating.

Below is my ConTeXt MkIV code. It gives `M0H0S0` for all 4 test cases. I would expect `M0H1S0`, `M0H1S1`, `M1H0..`, `M1H0..`.

```
\mainlanguage[hu]

% adapted from magyar.ldf (LaTeX Babel)
\def\thinspaced#1{%
  % Dat: `!' at the end of the word is OK, but at the beginning it makes the
  %      word unhyphenatable. Imp: maybe \nobreak\hskip\z@skip?
  % Dat: this is math-mode safe, because \ifhmode is false in math mode
  \doifmode{*hu}{
  % THE COMMENTED CODE SHOULD WORK BELOW
  %\ifmmode% \ifhmode and \ifmmode are never true
  %  \ifdim\lastskip>\dimexpr0pt\relax
  %    \unskip\penalty\@M\kern.1em% \thinspace is .16667em
  %  \else
  %    \kern.1em
  %  \fi
  %\fi
  % TEMPORARY MODE TEST CODE BELOW
  \ifmmode\/M1\else\/M0\fi
  \ifhmode\/H1\else\/H0\fi
  \ifdim\lastskip>\dimexpr0pt\relax\/S1\else\/S0\fi
  }%
  \string#1
}

\catcode`\:=\active \edef:{\thinspaced:}

\starttext
Test1: Test1

Test2 :Test2

Mathtest1 \math{20:30} Mathtest 1

Mathtest2
\startformula
20:30
\stopformula
Mathtest2

\stoptext
```

Note that I just started to use ConTeXt, have no deep TeX coding knowledge, used LaTeX before but that is not good enough for my typographic needs.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Henri's answer pointed out that `\ifhmode` and `\ifmmode` works as intended; the problem was with `\edef` above.

Comment: To insert a small space before certain punctuation marks (`:`, `;`, `!` and `?`) add `\setcharacterspacing [frenchpunctuation]` to your document.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this setting. Unfortunately it puts explicit space character before the marks instead of kerning which also shows up in copypasted texts. But for now, it will do just fine. Still I would be courious how I would know inside that function whether I am in text mode. I am going to look at `\setcharacterspacing` source code.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam It actually doesn't put exlicit spaces.  It inserts glue nodes which are then probably converted to spaces by the PDF viewer's heuristic.  I'm not sure.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam You don't have to edit the answer into the question.  Most people know how to scroll down ;)

Comment: I was unsatisfied with the width of the `frenchpunctation` space, defined my own punctation with only `0.1em` spaces and now there are no more extra spaces before the marks in the resulting PDF. Everything works as intended. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `\edef:` you are freezing it to the mode which was active at the point of definition which is vertical mode.  For the definition to adapt dynamically, use `\def`.

```
\mainlanguage[hu]

% adapted from magyar.ldf (LaTeX Babel)
\def\thinspaced#1{%
  % Dat: `!' at the end of the word is OK, but at the beginning it makes the
  %      word unhyphenatable. Imp: maybe \nobreak\hskip\z@skip?
  % Dat: this is math-mode safe, because \ifhmode is false in math mode
  \doifmode{*hu}{
  % THE COMMENTED CODE SHOULD WORK BELOW
  %\ifmmode% \ifhmode and \ifmmode are never true
  %  \ifdim\lastskip>\dimexpr0pt\relax
  %    \unskip\penalty\@M\kern.1em% \thinspace is .16667em
  %  \else
  %    \kern.1em
  %  \fi
  %\fi
  % TEMPORARY MODE TEST CODE BELOW
  \ifmmode\/M1\else\/M0\fi
  \ifhmode\/H1\else\/H0\fi
  \ifdim\lastskip>\dimexpr0pt\relax\/S1\else\/S0\fi
  }%
  \string#1
}

\catcode`\:=\active \def:{\thinspaced:}

\starttext
Test1: Test1

Test2 :Test2

Mathtest1 \math{20:30} Mathtest 1

Mathtest2
\startformula
20:30
\stopformula
Mathtest2

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I borrowed that catcode line from some other place. So `\ifhmode` and `\ifmmode` works as intended.

Comment: Note that the typical way to define such commands in ConTeXt is to define a text mode command, say `\textthinspaced` and define a math mode command, say `\maththinspaced`, and then use `\def\thinspaced{\mathortext\maththinspaced\textthinspaced}`.